# write new content in a new line

Tags: bash

I'm new to bash. I know that in order to add some new content to the end of a text file, I should use this command:

```
cat >> test.txt
```

After running this, the command line will change to typing mode and I can type whatever I want to be added to the end of my file. The problem is that whenever I do this, the new content is added to the end of the last line. However, I want to start a new line and write my content in the new line. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3):

The problem you see is that the last line in the file doesn't have a new line at the end of it. One way to solve the problem is by typing a new line when your appending to the file.

Just type one extra <kbd>Enter</kbd> after what you have typed and then close the file.

Comment: but this way a blank line is created after the previous last line.

Comment: @Pablo Hmm? Either there's no newline at the end, so this just creates one new one (as in your question), or there's already a newline, in which case you don't need to press enter at all. Which is it?

Comment: @ChrisDown There seems to be no newline at the end, so when I add a new content, it is added to the end of the file. I added an `Enter` before my content (when the command line is in typing mode). This time a blank line was created at the end of the file and then my new content is added. I mean after doing this, there is a blank line between the previous last line and my new content. I don't want this blank line between 2 lines.

Comment: @Pablo If there's no newline at the end of the file, pressing enter won't create a blank line, just a newline for the final line in the file. If the file is `xxx`, then `<Enter>yyy<Enter>^D` creates `xxx\nyyy\n`. If it's `xxx\n`, then `<Enter>yyy<Enter>^D` creates `xxx\n\nyyy\n`.

Comment: @Pablo I can't recreate what you seem to be seeing: Using `cat >>file` to a file with no terminating newline, pressing `Enter` and then entering some text, would not create an empty line in the file.

Answer (score 0):

Another way of quickly creating a file with short text:

```
echo "Lorem ipsum" > tmp.txt
echo -e "Lorem ipsum\nNew line lorem ipsum" >> tmp.txt # -e makes echo interpret non-printable characters like \n or \t
```

Every time you add a new line this way it will sit on a new line.

Also, there is the ***heredoc*** way to create a file:

```
prompt $ cat << EOF > new.txt
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
adipiscing elit,sed do eiusmod tempor
incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud
exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut...
EOF
```